# External php does return with UserID 0

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I'm using joomla 3.2.

I have a wrapper menu item, and it's wrapper include the external php.

I'm connecting open joomla with this code:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '/..' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');    
$user = JFactory::getUser();

print_r ($user);
```

but my user object id is always 0. What could be happening?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script in your base Joomla folder:

```
<?php
// Initialize Joomla
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );

// Required Files
require_once (JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php');

// To use Joomla's Database Class
require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();

echo '<pre>' . print_r ($user, true) . '</pre>';
```

You need to open another Joomla page and login there (same browser).

Comment: I'm alredy logged in to joomla in site.
I'm insert this code to my external php file but not solved, the User array give me the guest user.

Comment: If i open this external php in browser not in the wrapper menu item, that give me the correct User datas, but this is just somethimes working.

So I think the problem is the wrapper frame.

I have red another solution to this problem where the resolve was this "$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();" but this isn't solved my problem :-/ the wrapper not have the id.

And i percepted not always give the user datas to the external page if i open that in his url.

Comment: Okay, problem is solved :-)
The wrapper menuitem's URL address must begin with www. like "WWW.siteame.com/xy.php".